# Batch loader issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I am making a batch game with some fancy stuff. I know you can make it pop up messages and such, but what I am interested in is a different popup: I want to make a loader.

For example, after you do one task this loader will pop up.
When the loader is finished the batch will continue. I'm trying to make a loader similar to one of these:

[image: Example loader]

This is the same popup style as the (MSG) command makes. I want to specify the title of this loading bar. Is this possible with batch? Is there a way to make this at all with `.VBS`?

This is how I generated the other popups in my batch:

```
echo X=MsgBox("Message Description",0+16,"Title") >msg.vbs
```

Comment: You're looking for a [progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+progress+bar).

Comment: What should the loading bar show? Do you want it to be functional?

Comment: well its a game im making about hacking. :P a text based game. the loader itself is simply for the show and getting the feeeling youre actually "doing something" xD i want it etc to say on top as title: breach executed (as an example( then it will just process up from 0 to 100 %  it will have not really any functions to it. exept that it puts the batch on hold until the l"loading" is done.then it will disapear displaying message. breach complete. and the batch will resume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

In a file called loadbar.bat, copy this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set max=16
SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%2") do set "var=%%i"
if not defined var if not "%~2"=="" set "max=%~2"
title Loading... 
if not "%~3"=="" title "%~3"
color 0a
set "top=É"
set "spaces="
set "bottom=È"
for /L %%i in (1,1,%max%) do (
   set "top=!top!Í"
   set "spaces=!spaces! "
   set "bottom=!bottom!Í"
)
set "top=!top!»"
set "bottom=!bottom!¼"

set /A loadnum=0, loadNum1=max-1
set "load="

:Loading
set "load=%load%²"
(
cls
echo                                 Loading "%~1"
echo                                 %top%
echo                                 º%load%!spaces:~0,%loadnum1%!º
echo                                 %bottom%
)
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set /A loadnum+=1, loadnum1-=1
if %loadnum% lss %max% goto Loading

cls
timeout 1 >nul
title
color
exit
```

And in your game, you can show the loadbar like this:

```
@echo off
start /wait loadbar "executing breach..." 5 "executing breach"
pause
```

The first parameter of loadbar is the text above the progressbar, the second the maximum number, the third the title.

Comment: not exactily what i looked for... but HOLY SHIT THAT WAS GOOD ! honestly i would like a loadbar as shown in pic in original post. but i dont even know if its poossblie so if not this would be the next best :D thanks :D (if someone know if/how to do what i showd in pic in original post please help) if not ima use this one :D  thanks man <3

Comment: OHH btw... about this loader u showed me. i am gonna have the loader file in a close by sub folder somewhere inside where the file thats gonne execute this is gonna be. i remember reading something about a  command that finds the file u look for no matter what sub directory of the directory the batch is.... but what was this comand again?? was it "dir"? or ?

Comment: @KevinKyoNightwolf `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b myfile.bat') do set myscript=%%i`